# cgit scan for repo owner even with enable-git-config=0

Tags: git, cgit

I installed cgit and now can access my git repos through browser. 
I have more than 5000 repos.

I use scan option and every time I click anything in browser cgit scan all repos for repo owner. It makes it extremely slow. I disabled git owner in cgit file but it doesn't help. It's a part of my cgitrc:

```
enable-git-config=0
enable-gitweb-owner=0
remove-suffix=1
scan-path=/opt/projects/git
```

It's what I see in the log file when I browse my repos:

```
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7250/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7251/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7254/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7253/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7255/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7256/: Success (0)
Jan 25 11:36:50 ht-vm-cgit rc.local[1033]: Error reading owner-info for /opt/projects/git/7257/: Success (0)
```

And so on for all of them. How I can tell git not to look for owner info?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from [the source code](https://github.com/metajack/cgit/blob/master/scan-tree.c#L62) `cgit` is trying to get the owner of the repo from `/etc/passwd` calling [getpwuid](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) on the root directory of the repo.

Is the owner in `/etc/passwd`? I don't think `enable-gitweb-owner` controls that.

Comment: No. Owners are not /etc/passwd. I really need to disable this. The only way I can it's to change the source code?

Comment: I don't see any option to controls that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try **enable-index-owner** https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/tree/cgitrc.5.txt

```
enable-index-owner:
   Flag which, when set to "1", will make cgit display the owner of
   each repo in the repository index. Default value: "1".
```